# What are some good reference texts on history of Hinduism?

Tags: history

I am asking about books written by historians on the state/nature of Hinduism through various centuries.

Comment: Hi, we are not encouraging [book recommendation](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/130/93) questions on our Hinduism.SE site. Please consider this from next time. :)

Comment: Your question is too broad and there can be different point of views on it,please edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Kannadasan, who is a popular writer in south wrote a book called "[Arthamulla Indhu Madham](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12297749-arthamulla-hindu-matham-vols-1-10)" which means "Meaningful Hinduism" is a nice book on Hinduism.

Comment: Please add more information, This more looks like comment.